# jQuery width of a button element

Tags: jquery, dom

I need to get the exact width( the width that browser shows and can be seen with inspect element or such tools) of a button element with class="btn-default"

Here's the code :

I tried this:

```
  $('.btn-default').each(function(index, value){
      btn = $(this)[0].offsetWidth;
      console.log(btn);

});
```

and this :

```
$('.btn-default').each(function(index, value){
      btn = $(this).width();
      console.log(btn);

});
```

and innerWidth() and outerWidth()

THEY ALL SHOW WRONG VALUES

I have to add that when I do this:

```
  $('.btn-default').each(function(index, value){
      btn = $(this).width(false);
      console.log(btn);

});
```

It shows this which has the right size in it's offsetWidth attribute :

```
[button.btn btn-default, context: button.btn btn-default, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]
0: button.btn btn-default
accessKey: ""
attributes: NamedNodeMap
autofocus: false
baseURI: "file:///home/pkhodaveissi/Work/Hadi/trade.html"
childElementCount: 0
childNodes: NodeList[1]
children: HTMLCollection[0]
classList: DOMTokenList
className: "btn btn-default"
clientHeight: 28
clientLeft: 1
clientTop: 1
clientWidth: 134
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap
dir: ""
disabled: false
draggable: false
firstChild: text
firstElementChild: null
form: null
formAction: ""
formEnctype: ""
formMethod: ""
formNoValidate: false
formTarget: ""
hidden: false
id: ""
innerHTML: "Find a Product"
innerText: "Find a Product"
isContentEditable: false
labels: NodeList[0]
lang: ""
lastChild: text
lastElementChild: null
localName: "button"
name: ""
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
nextElementSibling: null
nextSibling: text
nodeName: "BUTTON"
nodeType: 1
nodeValue: null
offsetHeight: 30
offsetLeft: 555
offsetParent: body
offsetTop: 452
offsetWidth: 136
onabort: null
onbeforecopy: null
onbeforecut: null
onbeforepaste: null
onblur: null
onchange: null
onclick: null
oncontextmenu: null
oncopy: null
oncut: null
ondblclick: null
ondrag: null
ondragend: null
ondragenter: null
ondragleave: null
ondragover: null
ondragstart: null
ondrop: null
onerror: null
onfocus: null
oninput: null
oninvalid: null
onkeydown: null
onkeypress: null
onkeyup: null
onload: null
onmousedown: null
onmousemove: null
onmouseout: null
onmouseover: null
onmouseup: null
onmousewheel: null
onpaste: null
onreset: null
onscroll: null
onsearch: null
onselect: null
onselectstart: null
onsubmit: null
onwebkitfullscreenchange: null
onwebkitfullscreenerror: null
outerHTML: "<button class="btn btn-default">Find a Product</button>"
outerText: "Find a Product"
ownerDocument: document
parentElement: div.grhb
parentNode: div.grhb
prefix: null
previousElementSibling: p
previousSibling: text
scrollHeight: 28
scrollLeft: 0
scrollTop: 0
scrollWidth: 134
spellcheck: true
style: CSSStyleDeclaration
tabIndex: 0
tagName: "BUTTON"
textContent: "Find a Product"
title: ""
translate: true
type: "submit"
validationMessage: ""
validity: ValidityState
value: ""
webkitInsertionParent: null
webkitPseudo: ""
webkitShadowRoot: null
webkitdropzone: ""
willValidate: true
__proto__: HTMLButtonElement
context: button.btn btn-default
length: 1
__proto__: Object[0]
```

Comment: `$(this).width()` not working?

Comment: surprisingly no! It shows a different value, It's been hours and I'm exhausted!

Comment: Can you please add your code in jsfiddle!

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I think that if it is an `input` type tag, I think the DOM element is in someway replaced by the OS's/brwoser's render of the type of element. you probably want to check the _rendered_ width of the element...

Comment: Where is your script? before or after the DOM elements? Is it wrapped in `$(function(){ ... });` ? `$(value).outerWidth()` should work fine regardless.

Comment: Tim B James: my script is included in my question

Deepak:In js fiddle it returns the right value so there's no point in that

thanks to everyone

Comment: @PooriaKhodaveissi Your code is yes, but you have not answered my questions. Is the script in the head, after the html? Sounds as though it is returning the wrong value before the width has been properly set.

Comment: @TimBJames no, It's in a different .js file and in a document.ready function

Comment: @TimBJames: you noticed that the answer from user261... below did returned the right value, how this is possible? I do just the same but with jquery and in a different file and It doesn't return the right value, wrong value again!!!

Comment: @PooriaKhodaveissi The answer from user261... gives you the correct value possibly because the button has already been rendered and styled, then you are clicking the button to get the value.

Comment: @TimBJames Yeah I got that a while later, and I did mention it in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that my script was in a document.ready function and maybe some properties were not set at that time, I changed that to window.load and that worked just fine...

thanks to all of you for the effort and time, that meant a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<button id="getVal" onclick="wValue()">get Width</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function wValue() {
                var wVal = $("#getVal").width();
                alert(wVal);
            }
        </script>
```

You use $(".name") for class or $("#name") for ID

Comment: You are using jQuery, should be no need to use `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange behaviour. It's likely down to browsers giving the button tags a default padding. This is a nasty workaround, but it works...

```
$('.btn-default').each(function(index, value){
   console.log($(this).css('width').replace('px',''));
});
```

Created a jsFiddle of this to show the behaviour at http://jsfiddle.net/wGMka/

Comment: That just showed me my latest results,

anyway thanks for the effort

Comment: Here's where you were wrong dear:

width() just returns the width of element disregarding the padding and border but
if you do outerWidth() It'll do the trick and return width + padding and border...

Here's your fiddle with my edit:
http://jsfiddle.net/NeECP/